# What is a Data-to-Segment Delay (MAX7219)

Tags: led, led-matrix

My guess is how long the data takes to be shown as a segment/digit. Is that true? In the datasheet is says 2.35ms but I would need 1ms or below. Is there a faster alternative? [Datasheet](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi3r_rQ383bAhUkLsAKHePdDyYQFgg5MAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sparkfun.com%2Fdatasheets%2FComponents%2FGeneral%2FCOM-09622-MAX7219-MAX7221.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3tAOpXuJC7QVX38CZgOzvB) (Page 3 at the bottom)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The maximum data-to-segment time is primarily limited by the scanning frequency. The internal oscillator in the MAX7219 governs how fast it can update the digits. The minimum scanning frequency for all 8 digits is 500Hz, so it takes 2ms to update all of the digits. Suppose you change the data value for some digit/segment in the display just after that same segment was updated...you have to wait for the scanning to come back to that digit again before the new value would be visible. So, the worst case delay is equal to the maximum time to scan through all of the digits plus a little more for the internal registers to be updated.

There are many faster alternatives. This would be an easy thing to do with a microcontroller. On the other hand, no human will be able to observe the difference, so it's not clear why you want to do this.

Comment: Your answer doesn't actually provide clarification on what the OP asked. The main question was 'What is Data-to-Segment delay?' which you sort of hinted at, but it needs more of a definitive 'This is what it means' sort of answer. As for it is not clear why the OP wants to do this, that doesn't matter. Some designs have certain specs that need to be considered for many reasons.

Comment: We don't recommend specific products here. I would suggest that you choose your favorite microcontroller and code away.

Comment: @MCG I tried to improve the explanation.